# How to install Bugzilla using WAMP ?

Tags: wamp, bugzilla, tracker

I want to install Bugzilla to my computer.I have WAMP server installed.Is there a way to add Bugzilla using WAMP server?

Comment: WAMPServer does not come with Perl by default and Bugzilla requires Perl. You will have to find another Bug Tracking suit to run on WAMPServer, or install Perl on your PC and configure it with WAMPServer

Comment: @RiggsFolly Thank you  :)

Comment: I install the Perl in wamp server and config. what are me doing now? please tell me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the documentation to install Bugzilla on a Windows environment : https://bugzilla.readthedocs.io/en/5.0/installing/windows.html

In this documentation there is a special page to configure Apache (which is embedded in WAMP) to run your bugzilla instance : https://bugzilla.readthedocs.io/en/5.0/installing/apache-windows.html#apache-windows

You have to :

> - Uncomment LoadModule cgi_module modules/mod_cgi.so at the beginning of
>     the file to enable CGI support.
> - Uncomment `AddHandler cgi-script .cgi`
>     to register .cgi files as CGI scripts. For this handler to work, you
>     must create a key in the Windows registry named
>     `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.cgi\Shell\ExecCGI\Command` with the default value
>     pointing to the full path of perl.exe with a -T parameter. For example
>     `C:\Perl\bin\perl.exe -T` if you use ActivePerl, or
>     `C:\Strawberry\perl\bin\perl.exe -T` if you use Strawberry Perl.
> - Add an Alias and a Directory for Bugzilla:
>
> httpd.conf :

```
Alias "/bugzilla/" "C:/bugzilla/"
<Directory "C:/bugzilla">
    ScriptInterpreterSource Registry-Strict
    Options +ExecCGI +FollowSymLinks
    DirectoryIndex index.cgi index.html
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

And then restart Apache.